# About Material3 Toolbar DynamicColors

Tags: android, material-design

I'm using Material3 Theme. `Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar`

Now the background of bottom navigation view was changed into the Dynamic Color automatically
But for the toolbar, it doesn't work.

`DynamicColors.applyToActivitiesIfAvailable(getApplication());`

Comment: This theme has an ActionBar. You can either remove it with "windowNoTitle"=true attribute or set your toolbar as action bar. With the second way i think it will by styled correctly out of the box.